# Syncing permissions between a Database project and a database using Visual studio

Tags: database, visual-studio, database-project, datadude

I have a database project in visual studio (2008) that I am using to keep my database structure in a version control system (Git).   I use the data schema compare tool in VS to maintain this database project.  The issue that I'm encountering is that I keep losing my permissions for new objects.

So how do I:

1. Capture these permissions using the schema compare tool.
2. Apply these permissions to a server using the schema compare tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method to capture and apply the permissions that I have found is to go into tools -> options -> database tools -> schema compare and uncheck the ignore permissions checkbox. Then run the schema comparision and apply updates.

**Note:** That this will update every object with permissions in your schema.  I have been capturing the permission after I sync my schema changes and then resetting the ignore permissions checkbox